# How do I search array of objects with nested values and filter it by search value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object, filtering

In a React app I have an array to display details from json data. Each object has a property called "fieldChange" which contains an object, which has varying key value pairs.

I'm trying to create a search bar that a user can filter the display by input. Thus far I'm able to filter by any of the regular object properties but stuck on how to also filter by the nested objects key or value. Since the properties vary between each object, I can't target any specific one.

JSON

```
[{
        "entity": "invalid",
        "timeStamp": "2022-09-12 05:57:12.397",
        "userId": 14,
        "source": "JeninReceiptValues",
        "action": "Update",
        "fieldChange": {
            "RecAmount": "553.0",
            "AppraisedBy": "5",
            "RecAmountNotes": "Found match in list. Deducted 33%./Set RecValue to 552.75"
        }
    },
    {
        "entity": "valid",
        "timeStamp": "2022-09-12 05:57:13.600",
        "userId": 1180,
        "source": "RESON_UpdateCarBody",
        "action": "Create",
        "fieldChange": {
            "Body": "Sedan"
        }
    }
}]...
```

Search Component

```
const SearchBar = ({ logs, setSearch }) =>{

    const handleSubmit =(e) => e.preventDefault()

    const handleSearchChange =(e) => {
        if (!e.target.value) return setSearch(logs)

        const value = e.taget.value

        const searchResult = logs.filter(log => log.source.toLowerCase().includes(value) || log.action.toLowerCase().includes(value) || log.entity.toLowerCase().includes(value))
        setSearch(searchResult)
    }

    return(
        <header>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <input
                    className="search__input"
                    type="text"
                    id="search"
                    onChange={handleSearchChange}
                />
            </form>
        </header>
    )

}

export default SearchBar

}
```

Not sure how to implement this. Any help appreciated.

Tried the following;

```
    console.log(logs.filter( log => {
      return Object.values(log.fieldChange).flat(y=>log===(//---(e.target.value)---'Sedan'))
    }) )
```

which logs out;

```
map 
(12) [Array(0), Array(1), Array(0), Array(0), Array(0), Array(1), Array(0), Array(0), Array(0), Array(1), Array(0), Array(0)]
0
: 
[]
1
: 
['Sedan']
2
: 
[]
3.......
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to convert everything to an array in the call back function like this.

```
const filteredData = logs.filter(item => {
    const mainKey_values = Object.values(item)
    const fieldChange_keys = Object.keys(item.fieldChange)
    return mainKey_values.toString().toLowerCase().includes(lowercasedValue) || 
    fieldChange_keys.toString().toLowerCase().includes(lowercasedValue)
    });
```

the (lowercasedValue) is just a variable for the event.target.value.

As pertains to the question, by applying Object.keys on the nested object we can iterate over the keys and convert them back into a string which allows the comparison with the entered value by which to filter.
Did the same for the regular keys by their values for simplicity sake.